# How to store Go's current time (hour-minute-seconds) on Postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, go

I want to store user checkin and checkout time (hour, minute, and second) on a Postgres table (the column type is of course **time**) via Go

```
query := `INSERT INTO oc_log (userid, userdate, checkin_time, checkin_location, checkout_time, checkout_location) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)`

err := db.QueryRow(query, userid, time.Now().Format("01-02-2006"), time.Now().Clock(), checkinlocation, "", "").Scan(&tmpid)
```

The go linter complains that

> multiple-value time.Now().Clock() in single-value context

How to fix this?

Comment: Golang driver on postgres suport time.Time type.It's well converted between time.Time <---> timestamp (without time zone)/date

Comment: Would an OS timestamp (ex: unixTimestamp := now.Unix() ) not be sufficient when storing on the DB? Is there an advantage to using time.Now over now.Unix (other than universal to OS maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `time.Time` values and let the driver worry about how to encode and decode them:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE foo (t timetz)")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    now := time.Now()
    _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO foo VALUES ($1)", now)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var t time.Time
    err = db.QueryRow("SELECT t FROM foo").Scan(&t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(now.Format(time.RFC3339)) // 2019-09-18T10:22:36+02:00
    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339))   // 0000-01-01T10:22:36+02:00
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=20268:20310#L583), here is the signature of `Clock`

```
func (t Time) Clock() (hour, min, sec int)
```

Clock returns three value. You need to save them separately if that is what you want.

Alternatively, you can save into the db a stringified version of the time.

```
time.Now().String()
```

Or if you want to save the date according to a certain format

```
time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") // use a date format
```

Or you can simply save `time.Now()` directly into the db and later when you'll retrieve the date, you'll format it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the time according to your desired format, then you can use the below code snippet

```
tt := time.Now().Format("02-01-2006 15:04:05")
t,_ := time.Parse("02-01-2006 15:04:05",tt)
```

You can insert this **t** in the postgres table